# Firestore Regex Rules - Security

Tags: regex, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to use regex to match an email for Firestore rules.

```
return request.resource.data.email.matches('/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i');
```

I pulled the regex directly from the Firebase documentation. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/regex

The problem is it doesn't match my email. I put it into a regex checker and it seems like the `\\.`  is causing the issue. It won't pick up my email, but if I try `\.`(which will work in the regex validator) - then Firestore rules throw an error.

```
firestore.rules:47:83 - ERROR Missing 'match' keyword before path.
!  firestore.rules:47:83 - ERROR Unexpected '/.'.
!  firestore.rules:47:85 - ERROR mismatched input '[' expecting {'{', '/', PATH_SEGMENT}
!  firestore.rules:47:95 - ERROR Unexpected '$'.
!  firestore.rules:47:96 - ERROR Missing 'match' keyword before path.
!  firestore.rules:47:99 - ERROR mismatched input ')' expecting {'{', '/', PATH_SEGMENT}
!  firestore.rules:81:5 - ERROR Unexpected 'allow'.
!  firestore.rules:87:3 - ERROR Unexpected '}'.
```

For reference the email I'm testing against is

```
email: "test@gmail.com"
```

Comment: "*it doesn't match my email*"  - where? In the online regex checking Web site or in Firebase?

Comment: Firebase. I'm testing locally against the emulator (it also fails when published).

In short 

Works on the online regex validator :

/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i'

Fails on the online regex validator: 

'/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i'

Both fail in Firestore rules locally and when publishing the Firestore rules.

Comment: I'm not familiar with firebase, but I think you need to get rid of the single quotes around the pattern?

Comment: @CAustin Same, regex literal wrapped in a string literal just doesn't make any sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems in your rules.

1. You're mixing literal RegEx syntax (starting/ending with `/`) with string-based syntax (enclosed in quotes).
2. The `/i` at the end indicates you want a case-insensitive match, but I don't think that is supported in Firestore security rules.

The simplest solution is to make it all into a string, and just add `a-z` ranges to allow both uppercase and lowercase.

This works for me:

```
match /77724566/{doc} {
  allow write: 
    if request.resource.data.email.matches(
      '^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$'
    );
}
```

In here `77724566` is my collection name.

Comment: The `/i` flag seems to be supported in the documentation here https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/regex

Comment: It was indeed the /i that was causing the issue here. 

The documentation needs an update - it says 

An i trailing the regular expression literal construction (e.g. /yes/i) indicates the matching will be case insensitive. Other regular expression modifiers are not supported at this time.

The /i is contained in the example as well. Reference doc : https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/regex

Comment: @CAustin: that's for the Realtime Database; this is for Firestore. I made the same mistake initially. ;-) --- And same for: Jesse: that documentation is for Realtime Database, not for Firestore.